ACF Flexible content - Have rows function not working
I am building a website where there is a flexible content inside taxonomy page in woocommerce (tag / category page)
But the flexible content is not working the have_rows() function is returning me false even if the data is well completed. When i dump the field it shows me an array with data.
I have tried both ways explained by ACF
    <?php
                $current_category = get_queried_object();

        if( have_rows('contenu_flexible', $current_category) ): 

            // Loop through rows.
            while ( have_rows('contenu_flexible', $current_category) ) : the_row();


OR
    <?php
                $current_category = get_queried_object();

        if( have_rows('contenu_flexible', $current_category->taxonomy.'_'.$current_category->term_id) ):
            // Loop through rows.
            while ( have_rows('contenu_flexible', $current_category->taxonomy.'_'.$current_category->term_id) ) : the_row();



Both are not working

I have tried to check it but I don't find any issues as you mentioned, can you please verify that whatever field name you've used are correct once?

Yes unfortunately the variables are correct and this exact fields works on post.php but not in taxonomy page :(

can you help me with exact where you're using this code, because I have tried it within theme by overriding woocommerce template in theme so!

Yes of course, here is my hierarchy I am using "taxonomy-product-tag.php" and in this file I have a condition and which use "get template part" and the final code i linked is in "taxonomy-product-tag_n2.php". I also tried to not use the get template part and used the code below inside the first file and still not working

Actually, WooCommerce tag taxonomy is product_tag so your template should be taxonomy-product_tag.php and I have already tried with this file and it's working for me, let me know if you are not able to get it resolved, Thanks!

Hello, I finally found this issue thanks to you. When you confirmed me that the code was right I deleted every lines in my functions.php and the issue was coming from a custom add_action who was supposed to order from stock but got conflicted in taxonomy page thank you !

That's sounds great, Thanks for the update, Happy to help!
